# mysql update data check multi table where not exist

Tags: php, mysql

I have 5 tables. how to update one data that check if this data has not already exist in all the 5 tables.

I know something like `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, but not find an example for multi-tables.

Now I use some poor query like:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE table1 SET image = '' WHERE image = '".$image."' ");
mysql_query("UPDATE table2 SET image = '' WHERE image = '".$image."' ");
mysql_query("UPDATE table3 SET image = '' WHERE image = '".$image."' ");
mysql_query("UPDATE table4 SET image = '' WHERE image = '".$image."' ");
mysql_query("UPDATE table5 SET image = '' WHERE image = '".$image."' ");
mysql_query("UPDATE table1 SET image = '".$image."' WHERE id = '".$id."'");
```

First update empty value for each table where the data is `DUPLICATE` then insert the value. this will cost more mysql connects I think... So how to use less query do this update? Thanks.

**EDIT1:** tried something below, it will update the value ignore to check if the value has already exited in one table of the five.

```
mysql_query("
UPDATE table1,table2,table3,table4,table5 
SET table1.image='".$image."' 
WHERE table1.id='".$id."' 
AND table1.image!='".$image."' 
AND table2.image!='".$image."' 
AND table3.image!='".$image."' 
AND table4.image!='".$image."' 
AND table5.image!='".$image."'
");
```

Comment: WHy do you have 5 identical tables?

Comment: And if the image is not in any of the 5, which table should it be INSERTed into?

Comment: @ypercube, I'm working for an image thumb create job. 5 tables are different structure, But I want avoid DUPLICATE thumb image url to insert in different table. Thanks.

Comment: You can probably then use something like `UPDATE ... WHERE NOT EXISTS (...) AND NOT EXISTS (...) AND ...`

Comment: But it would make much more sense to have the `imageURL` in one table (with a UNIQUE Index on it) and only referencing ids in all the 5 ones.

Comment: @ypercube, I tried chris's advise, try `where not exists`, but return `You can't specify target table 'table1' for update in FROM clause`

Comment: I see no `FROM table1` in chris' answer...

Comment: @ypercube, ok, cris's answer could avoid the value where not existed in `table2`,`table3`,`table4`,`table5`,  it will update some value that `DUPLICATE` in `table1`. so I tried to added `table1`, caused that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, i think this is what you asked for

```
update table1 AS t1
         LEFT JOIN table1 AS t1copy
           ON t1copy.image = '$image'       
   set t1.image = '$image'
 where t1.id = $id
   and t1copy.image IS NULL
   and not exists(select 1 from table2 where table2.image = '$image' )
   and not exists(select 1 from table3 where table3.image = '$image' )
```

Comment: thanks for answer, but I only want to insert `$image` into `table1.image` and avoid `DUPLICATE` from (`table1.image` `table2.image` `table3.image` `table4.image` `table5.image`) . not insert the value into 2 tables, thanks.

Comment: it does not insert into any tables. it performs the equivalent of your first 5 querys. I choose to do this because your explanation of what you want is not clear, but your code speaks precisely.

Comment: sorry for I can not explain my question well,  As my `EDIT1` code desire, I want update one value into `table1` but I want check first: if this value has already in one table of five, do not update. If all 5 table have no this value, do update. Hope you can understand and help me, regards.

Comment: this caused error  `You can't specify target table 'table1' for update in FROM clause`

Comment: ah ok. In that case, i don't have an answer.

Comment: ok, thanks for your work for me. I will try to find a best solution based your code.

Comment: @ypercube, what a greater code it works! Thanks. On another hand, I find some way, first for 5 table UNION search, if `mysql_num_rows = 0`, do a update, this would cost 2 queries. But I am not sure which way is more efficient.(cost less time and lower RAM used). maybe do some further test.

Comment: `NOT EXISTS` should be (slightly or more) faster when the duplicate exists. If it finds it in the 2nd table for example, it doesn't need to search the rest 3 tables. A UNION will have to get (count) all rows that match from all 5 tables even if there is matching case in 1st or 2nd table.

Comment: @ypercube, nice! I saw the mysql manual said *"Currently, you cannot update a table and select from the same table in a subquery."* so I guess that means just subquery, not join.